# gradle dependencie managment with sub dependencies (nested depenencies)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have three projects

```
../server/modelProject/
../client/apiProject/
../client/appProject/
```

The `apiProject` need to depends on `modelProject` and `appProject` need to depends on `apiProject`.
`Api` need the `models` and the app need the `api`. Just a normal thing, i think :)

My `modelProject` have nothing special.

The `apiProject` setup looks like this:

### settings.gradle

```
include ':app', 'models'
project(':models').projectDir = new File('../../server/modelProject')
```

### build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':models')
}
```

Last my `appProject`:

### settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':api'
project(':api').projectDir = new File("../client/apiProject")
```

### build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':api')
}
```

I expected that my `appProject` on which I'm working on, depend on `api` which depends on `model` so that I can use all models classes in my `appProject` too. But it isn't so.

I get the following error:

> Project with path :models could not be found in projects ':api'.

So solve these problem I can expand the `appProjects` *settings.gradle* to:

```
include ':app', ':api', ':models'
project(':api').projectDir = new File('../client/apiProject')
project(':models').projectDir = new File('../../server/modelProject')
```

But this isn't a nice solution and not what I expected.

So my question:
It this the normal behavior of `gradle`? Or do I make something wrong? Can I make any changes that `appProject` only depends on `apiProject` which will automatically include the `modelProject?

Answer (score 1):

Your first settings.gradle file will not be used. From the gradle docs:

> A multiproject build must have a settings.gradle file in the root project of the multiproject hierarchy. It is required because the settings file defines which projects are taking part in the multi-project build

So your second approach with listing all projects in one settings.gradle file is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct and working. But, for example, the play-services from google have a dependency to the guava lib. Isn't this the same? Only that they get it from remote repository and I from local?!

Comment: I guess the main difference is that when you're depending on play services, you're depending on a AAR library and the same goes for the transitive dependencies. If you set up your apiProject to depend on the compiled artifact of the modelProject then it would probably work, BUT whenever you want to compile a new version of modelProject you would have to do it seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Just one `settings.gradle` is enough. Your project file tree should be something like:

Project

- client

  - apiProject

    - build.gradle
  - appProject

    - build.gradle
- server

  - build.gradle
- setings.gradle
- build.gradle

settings.gradle ->

```
include ':app', ':api', ':models'

project(':app').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,'client/appProject')
project(':api').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,'client/apiProject')
project(':models').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,'server/modelProject')
```

And your dependency flow is you explained.

Comment: No, not really. I'm working on `appProject`. So I use the `settings.gradle` from `appProject`. Or is it the wrong way? Your "Project" looks like a wrapper over all projects...

Comment: Yeah try to not bind settings to specific module.

Answer (score 0):

you need 1 top level settings.gradle in the root folder containing all of your modules if you're going to create dependencies between modules﻿

Comment: Your answered looks similar to these http://stackoverflow.com/a/32713512 so please checkout my comment on this...